# 'Expected [200] but was [401]' Bearer Token failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, security, testing

I was trying to make a test of a method that is secured and can be authorized using a bearer token.
Exactly, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004367/bearer-token-failure-mockmvc-test-java-spring-boot#comment110971491_48004465) way to accomplish it, however, I still get the 401 Http Unauthorized error.

**Test**

```
@Test
void list() throws Exception {
        String token = "YWxndW5fdG9rZW5fY29uX2FsZ3VuYV9mcmFzZV9zZWNyZXRhOmF4ZWwxNkBob3RtYWlsLmNvbQ==";
    
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/fch-fiscal/tipos-correos")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .param("page", "0")
            .param("size", "3"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.ALL_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$['<key>']").value("<value>"));
}`
```

**Controller**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> list(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "3") int size
    ) {
        try {
            List<TiposCorreos> tiposCorreos;
            Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);

        Page<TiposCorreos> pageTipoCorreo;
        if(name == null) {
            pageTipoCorreo = repository.findAll(paging);
        } else {
            pageTipoCorreo = repository.findByNombreTipoContaining(name, paging);
        }

        tiposCorreos = pageTipoCorreo.getContent();

        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("Tipos de Correos", tiposCorreos);
        response.put("Página actual", pageTipoCorreo.getNumber());
        response.put("Elementos totales", pageTipoCorreo.getTotalElements());
        response.put("Páginas totales", pageTipoCorreo.getTotalPages());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}`
```

This is the code that i've tried so far, I use a previously generated Bearer token. I've seen other ways to mock the security but I don't really understand how to implement them.

**Edit: Stack Trace**

```
%TESTC  1 v2
%TSTTREE2,mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest,true,1,false,1,TipoCorreoControllerTest,,[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest]
%TSTTREE3,list(mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest),false,1,false,2,list(),,[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest]/[method:list()]
%TESTS  3,list(mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest)

%FAILED 3,list(mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest)
%TRACES 
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:637)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:214)
        at mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest.list(TipoCorreoControllerTest.java:58)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

%TRACEE 
%TESTE  3,list(mx.com.ficachi.master.tiposDeCorreo.controllers.TipoCorreoControllerTest)

%RUNTIME3023
```

Comment: Please share the full stack trace as well, it could help understand the origin of the issue.